# Loadresource from file

Tags: delphi, resources

How can i load resources form another file?
This is the script to load resources from the project:

```
function Loadhwid: string;
var
  ResourceLocation: HRSRC;
  ResourceSize: dword;
  ResourceHandle: THandle;
  ResourcePointer: pointer;
begin
  ResourceLocation := FindResource(hInstance, 'HWID', RT_RCDATA);
  ResourceSize := SizeofResource(hInstance, ResourceLocation);
  ResourceHandle := LoadResource(hInstance, ResourceLocation);
  ResourcePointer := LockResource(ResourceHandle);
  if ResourcePointer <> nil then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, ResourceSize - 1);
    CopyMemory(@Result[1], ResourcePointer, ResourceSize);
    FreeResource(ResourceHandle);
  end;
end;
```

But i want to know how to load resources from an external exe file(I know how to write the resources).
I want to use this script for an updater that works with HWID.

Answer (score 1):

Call `LoadLibraryEx` passing `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`.

Comment: Do you still need help?