# Data pointer from LockResource() is not the expected VS_VERSION_INFO structure

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7, embedded-resource, fileversioninfo

I want to load the binary data of a VERSION resource from an external EXE file. This should be fairly simple:

```pascal
var
  hFile: HMODULE;  // File=image to load
  hR: HRSRC;  // Resource handle
  hG: HGLOBAL;  // Loaded resource
  p: Pointer;  // Actual accessible data to the resource
  sDebug: AnsiString;
  sFile: Widestring;
begin
  // Commonly known to every Windows installation, 32-bit version.
  sFile:= 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\calc.exe';

  // WinAPI and https://stackoverflow.com/a/23035857/4299358 want both flags.
  hFile:= LoadLibraryExW( PWideChar(sFile), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE );

  // 2nd param=resource name/ID; 3rd param=resource type. Unlike FindResourceExA() where these are swapped.
  hR:= FindResourceA( hFile, PAnsiChar('#1'), PAnsiChar('#16') );  

  // Same results as above: returns valid handle. Just another valid way of wanting numeric IDs.
  {hR:= FindResourceA( hFile, PAnsiChar(1), PAnsiChar(16) );}

  // Both succeed in returning a valid handle and a non-empty pointer.
  hG:= LoadResource( hFile, hR );
  p:= LockResource( hR );

  // AnsiString will have the bytes $f0 $b2 $0b $00 $84 $03 $00, but not the
  // expected $bd $04 $ef $fe from VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.dwSignature after about 40 bytes.
  SetString( sDebug, PAnsiChar(p), 50 );
```

I get valid handles all the way through, and also a non-`nil` pointer. For debugging purposes I stuff the bytes into an `AnsiString` to then view its content. If I search for those bytes in the file I find them off by far from the resource I wanted (file position $585c0) - and it's the only occurrence of those bytes:

[image: pointer to $585c0 in CALC.EXE]

The `VS_VERSION_INFO` resource I wanted is found 388 KiB later at $b96f0 (one can even spot a preceding resource storing a PNG file - note the `IEND` chunk, most likely one of its icons). The expected bytes `$bd $04 $ef $fe` from `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.dwSignature` can be seen 40 bytes later:

[image: actual VERSIONINFO at $b96f0]

This is also confirmed by [Resource Hacker](https://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), showing where the resource resides in the binary file (see Status Bar with file position "B96F0") - it also confirms the resource has the name `1` (like many others) and is the only `VERSION` resource, so I'm not accidentially finding a different resource:

[image: Resource Hacker confirms $b96f0]

**What am I missing?** [`LockResource()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-lockresource) clearly explains:

> the return value is a pointer to the first byte of the resource

So there's not an offset I'm missing to add. I expected the bytes to contain the [`VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/verrsrc/ns-verrsrc-vs_fixedfileinfo), which should be nearby after 38 bytes of the [`VS_VERSIONINFO` pseudo structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/vs-versioninfo) (3 `WORD`s + 15 `WCHAR`s = 36 bytes at least with variable padding).

I **don't** want to use `GetFileVersionInfoW()` and `VerQueryValueW()` because I want to avoid [Windows being a man in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77655920/4299358) and because the file version is only one step - my goal is to read **any** resource reliably (not only those where the WinAPI provides helper functions).

I'm using Delphi 7 on Windows 7x64, so the debugged EXE is 32-bit and the loaded CALC.EXE is also ensured to be 32-bit (although that shouldn't matter). I failed to access the expected bytes of the version resource of other 32-bit EXE files, too.

Comment: In what your question? You got pointer to `VS_VERSIONINFO`. From this struct you can got pointer to `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`. In what problem?

Comment: @RbMm Look at my first screenshot - the pointer is 388 KiB off from any `VS_VERSIONINFO` resource. If I "_can got pointer to `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` then tell me how, because I also explained that I know where `VS_FIXEDILEINFO` resides in `VS_VERSIONINFO`. But for that I need a pointer to `VS_VERSIONINFO` to begin with. Have you tried reconstructing what I experienced?

Comment: https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/382964bc39fb27d56b0651c4c0579ec91397dc96/WINZ/app.cpp#L818C8-L818C8

Comment: @RbMm That's C++ with macros and no straight function names, with which I'm not that confident, and I see nothing that would explain the huge gap, like adding 0.38 million to the pointer I got. Be aware that Delphi 7 has no C++ compiler or environment. Also: [`LdrAccessResource`](https://www.freepascal.org/daily/packages/winunits-jedi/jwanative/ldraccessresource.html) is beyond the WinAPI - I'd like to avoid going to the Kernel directly. If it's obvious to you, please post a counter example in Delphi which works for you on f.e. CALC.EXE.

Comment: `FindResource()` returns `IMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY`, which you then use to find the resource data itself.

Comment: For me of course all works. LdrAccessResource no matter here, because it used to get pointer to VS_VERSIONIFO which you already have. Look code after, this api call . No any gap, errors, etc.. you need understand logic of code.

Comment: @RbMm That still doesn't explain why my code (logic) is flawed. And where. Which is the very point of my question: why it doesn't work and why the pointer is so very off from the bytes I expect, although `LockResource()` should get me right there. I'm stuck - if it would be obvious and easy I wouldn't have to ask. Why aren't you coming up with an actual answer and code in it? What could be the reason "_it_" works for you but not for me? Have you read I'm off ~397312 bytes? Not just 10 or 40?

Comment: @Luke Are you implying I have to add the file's position of the `IMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY` to the pointer I get? Otherwise I don't get what you wanted to hint with that comment, as the function returns an intermediate `HRSRC` to be used by `LoadResource()`.

Comment: Are you at all try understand my code ? Forget about LockResourse. You already have pointer to first struct. But you dont know how get from it begin of next struct. How work variable size structure. I not post answer because i not like how/what you ask. Correct question must be - how from pointer to `VS_VERSIONINFO` get pointer to `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`. I can give answer on such question. And you already view my code. But it not help to you. May be because you can not cut this logic from code

Comment: @AmigoJack Doh, I just copied and pasted your code without looking at it. You're passing the wrong parameter to `LockResource()`.

Comment: @Luke Thanks alot - I really didn't see my mistake there. Post it as answer, if you want. Now I see (as expected) `$bd $04 $ef $fe` after 40 bytes.

Comment: `LockResource( hG );` must be, not for `hR` and this api not need at all

Comment: @RbMm That's obvious **now** (thanks to Luke) and you could have pointed that out much sooner, but instead chose to tell me you did "_not like how/what_" I asked. Again: I know where `VS_FIXEDILEINFO` resides in `VS_VERSIONINFO` - that was **never** my problem. Judging from your horribly broken English (which hasn't improved since 2016) I'm convinced you understood me even less than I understood you. And `hR` is still needed for `LoadResource()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the wrong parameter to `LockResource()`. You should pass `hG` instead of `hR`.

Comment: and this return pointer to [`VS_VERSIONINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/vs-versioninfo) only. need then get pointer to `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` from it